# Adding a username alias using the command line

Tags: command-line, user-account, alias

How do I add a username alias using the command line?

I can do it fine using the preferences dialog through the "Advanced Options", but I need to do it during an installation script.

Can someone point me the right way?

Comment: See this link: http://serverfault.com/questions/102697/unix-user-alias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The information is accessible through `dscl`. To add the alias "visitor" and be able to use this username for guest login, use the following command:

`sudo dscl . -merge Users/Guest RecordName visitor`

Answer (score -2):

`sudo dscl . -merge /Users/usernameToAddAlias RecordName aliasName`

Comment: How does this differ from the answer already posted eight years ago?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).